# Regex get matches for ranges in IPv4 addresses with octet notation

Tags: regex, ip-address

I want to use a Regex expression to get all ranges in an IP Address provided.

Examples:

192.168.0-255.1  would return 0-255

192.168.0-255.1-10 would return 0-255 and 1-10

192.168.0-10,42,80-200.1-10,128-255 would return 0-10, 80-200, 1-10, 128-255.

BONUS: I'd also like to be able to separate these expressions into 4 different ones to determine which octet the IP range is in.
Example: 192.168-180.0.1 I'd like to get 168-180 here from an expression that looks for a match with only one period left of the substring and two periods somewhere in the right side of the substring.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$input = <<<INPUT
192.168.0-255.1
192.168.0-255.1-10
192.168.0-10,42,80-200.1-10,128-255
INPUT;

preg_match_all("/[0-9]+\-[0-9]+/m", $input, $m);

print_r($m);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0-255
            [1] => 0-255
            [2] => 1-10
            [3] => 0-10
            [4] => 80-200
            [5] => 1-10
            [6] => 128-255
        )

)
```

[0-9]+ 1 or more number
- "-" escaped
[0-9]+ 1 or more number